# Can't call function to send email using EmailJS

Tags: javascript, html, email

So I have a project that displays upcoming baby vaccinations. I am trying to send the upcoming vaccines outcome to any email requested. But for some reason I cannot even call the function.
HTML code for button:

```
<button id="mail" type="button" onclick="checkupFutureEmail()"> E-posta gönder </button>
```

Javascript:

[image]

[image]

I tried a lot of things asked AI for help but unfortunately really couldn't get any help. The main issue is the checkupFutureEmail() Function not even being called. Because I put console.log and when I click the button nothing happens.

Comment: Relevant code and error messages need to be included in your question *as text*, [not as pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/328193).  Just linking to screen shots makes it more difficult for people to help you.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: *"The main issue is the checkupFutureEmail() Function not even being called."* - Are there any errors or warnings on the browser's development console?  Have you used the browser's script debugger at all?  Can you provide a [mcve] as a [runnable code snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/328193) which demonstrates this problem?